# How to get the instance of an object in game make?

Tags: game-physics, game-maker

I am trying to use the "Create moving instance" tool of an object in game maker. The problem is that the `x` and `y` need to be the same as the object that is launching this new instances.

I tried putting `this.x` and `player.x` but i don't know how to say to my bullets that they need to have the initial `x` and `y` from my player.

Comment: (objectname).x and (objectname).y

Answer (score 0):

There is a "relative" checkbox in most action creation dialogs. If you check it, it will set the values relative to the object from which the action is called. x=0 y=0 will do the trick.

In GML code, you would do:

```
var bullet = instance_create(x, y, obj_bullet);
bullet.direction = direction; // shoot in direction the player is moving
bullet.speed = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're player's object is called `obj_player`, you can use `obj_player.x` and `obj_player.y`. This also assumes that you only have one player instance at a time *(which is true for most games)*.

**OR**,  if this action is in the object that you're wanting the position from, you can simply use `x` and `y`, or `self.x` and `self.y`. Both will accomplish the same feat. This option doesn't make the assumption as the option above, so it's technically safer to use.